# Performing statistical queries on Structured Streaming DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I currently have a Structured Streaming DataFrame that aggregates the count of timestamps into hourly categories (Hourly Windows). While it is nice to see the count, my objective is to find some information about the running query, such as the hour with the maximum count, minimum count, average number of timestamps per hour, total count during the 24 hours, etc...

My problem and question is how to access and query the active, running Streaming DataFrame to provide such information. Even further, I'd like to pull the entire row for the max and min entries (e.g. the hour that produced the highest/lowest timestamp count along with the quantity of timestamps counted)

Ideally, I would like to show the growing count of timestamps for each hour in the Streaming DataFrame AND provide the max, min, etc after each batch. However, I'm perfectly okay with just the max, min, etc if I can't have both done simultaneously.

For reference, here's the sample code I'm using along with some pseudo-code to show what I'm looking to do.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Sample").getOrCreate
import spark.implicits._
val stream = spark.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).text("file:///path/location")
val extracted = stream.select(extract_udf($value).cast(TimestampType) as 
  "timestamp").groupBy(window($"timestamp", "1 hour"), hour($"timestamp") as
  "hour").count.sort($"window")
val query = extracted.writeStream.queryName("time_table").outputMode("complete").
  format("console").start
query.awaitTermination
```

Desired pseudo-code

```scala
val max = findMaxRow(query) // Would extract from the row for a tuple (hour, count)
val min = // same as max
val runningCount = findTotalCount(query) // Would return the current count
val stats = List(max, min, count, etc)
val statsDF = stats.toDF
// Code to display stats along with the queried DataFrame
statsDF.writeStream.... ???
```

Also before anyone mentions it, I have searched through as much as I can and could not find the answer. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184812/how-to-compute-statistics-on-a-streaming-dataframe-for-different-type-of-columns) was the closest answer that I could find but does not address the issues of how to query the active streamed DataFrame and how to have both the streamed DataFrame and the stats DataFrame simultaneously.

Any help is appreciated, whether this is impossible to do or if I need to take a different approach.

Thanks!